# Does the MicroKORG XL+ have internal speakers?

Tags: keyboard, synthesizer

I just bought a MicroKORG XL+ and have plugged in the power adapter and turned this on. The volume is up but it makes no sounds. Does it have its own speaker? Or do I need to have this connected to an external speaker/amp/headphones?

Comment: A google for "MicroKORG XL+ manual" would likely have given you the answer.

Comment: I couldn't find it in the manual, which is why I was asking in this forum.

Comment: I see. That is good information to put in the post, since we get a lot of these type of questions. Then you'll avoid cranky type comments like these. Fortunately one of our less cranky users gave you an answer :)

Comment: From the manual: "1. [VOLUME] knob
This adjusts the volume of the OUTPUT jacks (L/MONO, R) and head-phone jack.". This is their way of saying that it does not have speakers, for future situations like these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have its own speaker, you'll need one.

In the back it has an output section with 3 outputs labeled as: R, L, and headphones. You can use those to connect the microKORG to amps, speakers, or headphones.